# react for loop with promise value

Tags: reactjs, axios, es6-promise

I am struggling with a react promise issue. I think I need to be able to use a state length in a for loop outside the axios .then function. Presently, the code below works when I replace **LEN** with a numerical value but will not work if I try to use label.length as that value does not exist when the for loop is called. Could anyone advise on the best way to handle this?
My code is crude as I'm new to js and react.

```
    export default function App() {
      const [label, setLabel] = useState([]);
      const handle = useFullScreenHandle();
      const [data, setData] = useState([]);
      const token = fetch('token');
      const headers = {
        'X-CSRF-Token': token,
        'Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa('cred')  
      }
    
      React.useEffect(() => {
        axios
          .get("url", {
            headers: headers
          })
          .then(result => {
            setLabel(Object.keys(result.data).map(key => result.data[key].title));
            setData(Object.keys(result.data).map(key => result.data[key].nid));
            len=label.length
          });
      }, []);
    
    
    console.log(length)
      for (let i = 0; i < **LEN**; i++) {
        i = Number(i)
        lab = label[i];
        dat = data[i];
        var stri = ({id:String(i), category: 'cat', label:"String(i)"+i});
    
        //JSON.stringify({artist: artist, title : title});
        nodes.push (stri);
        var ed = ({id:String(i),source:String(i),target:String(i+1),label:i});
        edges.push(ed);
    
      }
    
      var datada =  ({nodes: nodes, edges:edges});
let element = 
<>
 <Sigma graph={datada}></Sigma>
  return element
</>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent `datada` being unnecessarily recreated and causing unnecessary re-render, create `datada` with `useMemo`.

```
const datada = useMemo(() => {
  const nodes = [];
  const edges = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
    i = Number(i)
    lab = label[i];
    dat = data[i];
    var stri = ({ id: String(i), category: 'cat', label: "String(i)" + i });

    nodes.push(stri);
    var ed = ({ id: String(i), source: String(i), target: String(i + 1), label: i });
    edges.push(ed);
  }

  return { nodes: nodes, edges: edges };
}, [data, label]);
```

This will guarantee to re-create `datada` ONLY when `data` and `label` are changed.

Also, consider using `unstable_batchedUpdates` when updating `label` and `data`.

```
import { unstable_batchedUpdates } from "react-dom";

// code omitted
.then(result => {
  unstable_batchUpdates(() => {
    setLabel(Object.keys(result.data).map(key => result.data[key].title));
    setData(Object.keys(result.data).map(key => result.data[key].nid));
  });
});
```

This will make sure `lable` and `data` are updated at the same time, preventing `datada` being re-created twice.

Comment: Thank you for your response with this. The code you suggest above does work. BUt the underlying issue remains. As I am trying to call label.length after end of the .then loop, I continue to see the following behavior.
On the first run of the page, the label.length is zero. After the axios call, this value is a number (339, but whatever). However, the for loop works off the first of these two values so runs for 0 times. I wonder if anyone could advise on how to allow the label.length to return the second value?

Answer (score 0):

just get length in the for loop, should not cause any problem.

```js
    export default function App() {
      const [label, setLabel] = useState([]);
      ......
      React.useEffect(() => {
        axios
          .get("url", {
            headers: headers
          })
          .then(result => {
            setLabel(Object.keys(result.data).map(key => result.data[key].title));
            setData(Object.keys(result.data).map(key => result.data[key].nid));
            // len=label.length   <<<< not understand what is this, len is not defined
          });
      }, []);
    
      // use label.lenght directly here
      for (let i = 0; i < label?.length; i++) {
```